# How to mock up my pc as a usb host?

Tags: android, usb

Is there any possibilities to mock up my pc as the usb host and my android device using android usb api. If it so, how to set up the initial configurations? Please help me...

Comment: Under normal conditions, your PC is the USB Host. An android device is usually the device, but may (temporarily) act as a host (USB OTG).

Comment: @sstn is correct. Maybe you can explain a bit more in detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: To test the android usb accessory mode, i need an external usb accessory which are going to power the bus...Instead of using the external usb device as usb accessory, I mock up the pc as usb accessory device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get your phone to see your PC as a `UsbAccessory`, it must communicate via the AOA (Android Open Accessory) protocol.

From the PC, you must detect and determine which device is your phone. Then go through its interfaces; typically, the accessory one will be class 0xFF and subclass 0xFF.

Once you've determined that, you must then determine its read and its write endpoints. Typically the accessory interface has one read and write, and they are both bulk transfer (0x02) type.

Finally, using the write endpoint, send specific control request packets to the phone to activate it in "accessory mode". These packets are all outlined here:

http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/aoap/aoa.html

After they're sent, the phone will be able to see your PC as a `UsbAccessory` object (within the Android API). You can enumerate the accessories attached and begin communication via a `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, all documented here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html